# How to troubleshoot mysql_error()?

Tags: mysql, error-handling, sql-insert

I got the following `mysql_error()` message shown below. I get it from time-to-time and can figure them out by just looking back at my syntax.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'key, label, value, description, last_modified, username,
>   filepath, divid) SELE' at line 1

But now I have an error that I cannot seem to solve so I am getting around to asking a fairly simple question. How do I interpret the `mysql_error()` message Specifically, when it says "near".

- Near what?
- Where exactly do I look?

  - At the front-end of the query statement and that which precedes it?
  - Or the back-end of the query statement and that which follows it?

**Here's my actual query statement in PHP:**

```
mysqli_query($link, '
    INSERT INTO ' . DATASTORE . '(key, label, value, description, last_modified, username, filepath, divid)
    SELECT key, label, "' . $new_value . '", description, "' . $last_modified .'", "' . $authorized_username .'", "' . $new_filepath .'", "' . $target_divid .'"
    FROM ' . DATASTORE . '
    WHERE divid = "' . $source_divid . '"
') or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Have you checked each of the variable values?

Comment: Yes, I did @Jezzabeanz. The table columns are all text fields and the vars are all populated with string text. So are you inferring that I need to be looking at the SELECT side of the query and that which follows it to pinpoint the actually syntax error?

Comment: I would look on the INSERT side of the query. I've always hated the MySQL errors. When I look at your error it makes me think "okay so it's breaking at 'key'" Is your Datastore non-null, text only?

Comment: What about DATASTORE, can you show this value? Or try to generate full statement and show it.

Comment: Thanks @Devart. So what I did (well before posting here) was dummed it down. I removed all CONSTANTS and $vars and did a simple INSERT/SELECT using inline query values. *And it worked!* Then I slowly added back the dynamics of the query statement and it throws unexplained errors.

Comment: Also, key is a reserved word, use ` to quote these names.

Comment: Full list of reserved words - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of your 'key' field, which is SQL keyword. use '' or `` to quote that field

```
mysqli_query($link, '
INSERT INTO ' . DATASTORE . '(\'key\', label, value, description, last_modified, username, filepath, divid)
SELECT \'key\', label, "' . $new_value . '", description, "' . $last_modified .'", "' . $authorized_username .'", "' . $new_filepath .'", "' . $target_divid .'"
FROM ' . DATASTORE . '
WHERE divid = "' . $source_divid . '"') or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a backticks ` instead of a single quote ' ?

Comment: Ah brilliant @Perl99. I can't count the number of times I get tripped up by the use of a reserved MySQL keyword. Looks like this is another one of those times. I just happened to be chasing down an error that really wasn't a *syntactical* error...it was my use of a certain reserved column name. I'll test it out and post back and select this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It worked. once I put backticks around the column *key* on both the INSERT and SELECT lines in the query statement it worked! Again, I got tripped up by the use of a reserved MySQL keyword. Ugh.

Comment: **CONCLUSION:** In analyzing the `mysql_error()` message I believe what it is suggesting is it to **look at the beginning of the error message**. In this case the `near 'key, `...It is the *key* that was throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

If only it was so easy...I guess there is only so much information MySQL can give you.  My advice is to just use the message as a guide as to where the error is.

I would use a debugger or just echo the sql out, then use a database tool like SQLyog to run the query.  SQLYog (or something similar) can format the query to make it more readable.  The error could be anything from a typo, to a bracket not being closed properly.

Like everything, it just comes with practice.

Comment: Yeah, I know but what I could never figure out is when it says "`near`"...does that mean ***before***, or ***after*** or could it be ***either***?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the DATASTORE value. When you see that mysql says "near" it means before. So have a look at what is the value of DATASTORE when you get the error. Try to echo the query instead of executing it to see how it looks like and you will get the error.
In your situation the error is that there is not a space between DATASTORE and the (.
Also as Perl and other pointed out you have to backticks key since it is a reserved word for mysql

So edit your query this way and it should work:

```
mysqli_query($link, '
    INSERT INTO ' . DATASTORE . ' (`key`, label, value, description, last_modified, username, filepath, divid)
    SELECT `key`, label, "' . $new_value . '", description, "' . $last_modified .'", "' . $authorized_username .'", "' . $new_filepath .'", "' . $target_divid .'"
    FROM ' . DATASTORE . '
    WHERE divid = "' . $source_divid . '"
') or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Thanks @LelioFaieta. It was actually the ***key*** part of the error message that MySQL was informing me of.